# Auto-populating Storm Invoice

Tags: nodes

I'm using [Storm](http://drupal.org/project/storm) for a bunch of its varying functionality, and figure it thus makes sense to use its Invoice module as the final part of a multi-part project (see previous [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464750/combining-content-types-into-a-single-pdf-in-drupal-6) post).

Everything in Storm Invoice seems like it needs to be entered on the fly, all the time. What I need to have happen is for a computed field from another node or a view to provide a price to the Invoice module, autopopulating some fields. **Is this at all possible with Storm Invoice?**

**Addendum:** If Storm isn't the best way to create dynamically-generated invoices from node CCK fields, please suggest an alternative.

Comment: Remember to link to projects like [Storm](http://drupal.org/project/storm), especially if they're not well known projects like Panels, Views, etc. That'll make it a lot easier to figure out what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but maybe the [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) can be used, you can even use it to [fill another field](http://drupal.org/node/454758).

If you are ready for some custom code (although Computed Field will probably require some code too), you can implement [`hook_nodeapi()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) when `$op == 'prepare'`(or [`hook_prepare()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_prepare/7) in Drupal 7). There you can pre-fill new Invoice node (when `$node->nid` is not set, the node is being created).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't currently possible to auto-fill these fields in Storm Invoice.

If you're still looking to do this (realise this is an old question), then ask over at the [issues queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/storm) and we can help find a solution.